# Como alterar um célula de "Geral" para "Número" e adicionar vírgula?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

Estou aprendendo VBA e tive uma dificuldade para trasnformar uma coluna que possui valores formatados como "Geral" para número, além disso, preciso que esses valores sejam expressos com vírgula.

Valores atuais (amostra):

[image: Dias colunas que preciso transformar]

Sei que existe uma maneira mais simples de fazer isso sem usar VBA, porém gostaria de aprender e adquirir mais conhecimento na ferramenta.

Comment: Quantas casas decimais após a vírgula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para formatar, a [Propriedade Range.NumberFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff196401.aspx) é utilizada.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
Set rng = ws.Range("B:B", "E:E")

With rng
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
End With
```

## Explicação do código

### Planilha (Worksheet)

Declara a planilha a ser utilizada no VBA

```
 Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1")
```

### Range

Declara o range a ser utilizado, neste caso, colunas B e E.

```
 Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("B:B", "E:E")
```

### Lógica With (com)

Utiliza o with para realizar o que está dentro de With e End With somente dentro do Range `rng`

```
  With rng
  End With
```

### Formatar

Formata para números com duas casas decimais

```
.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
```

## Outra forma de utilizar e declarar este mesmo código

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Planilha1.Range("B:B", "E:E")

rng.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
```

## Verificar o NumberFormat

Para verificar alguns formatos de células, clicar em Mais formatos de Números

[image: Mais formatos de Números]

Verificar na Categoria Personalizado, alguns exemplos de NumberFormat

[image: NumberFormat]